# AWS CodePipeline - Automatically approve changesets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

Currently I have a CodePipeline set up with AWS and I've noticed that once it hits the staging step to deploy, I have to go in and manually approve the changeset in order to release any changes. Does anyone know a way I can avoid having to manually approve changesets and instead just automatically deploy/approve the changeset?

Comment: What is your pipeline looks like? Do you use a manual approval action in the staging stage? If so, you can remove the manual approval action.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `ActionMode` property of your CloudFormation action from `CHANGE_SET_REPLACE` to `CREATE_UPDATE` and then remove the manual approval and the `CHANGE_SET_EXECUTE` actions from your pipeline.

This will update your template within the first action without having separate steps to create then execute your change set.

You can find more info on configuring CloudFormation actions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-action-reference.html